# One file in chrome dev tools debugger is VM10628

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have opened the chrome dev tool debugger and one file `thelib.js` is named as `VM10628`, I thought it's code from chrome but I'll check it's contents and it match the file `thelib.js`. Anybody know why it's a name `VM10628`?

Comment: Try closing and re-open the browser.  Chrome sometimes holds onto the previous version of the js file, so it shows as VM####.

Comment: @Will now to file is VM11230.